# Cannot get cookies in WebBrowser in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

In my windows phone appliation, i'm using Web Browser. And my xaml code for the web browser is,

```
<phone:WebBrowser IsScriptEnabled="True" Navigating="NAvigating" Navigated="Uri_Navigated" x:Name="browserControl" Margin="-1,55,0,0" />
```

When i get cookies from **Uri_Navigated** function everything works fine, but when i try to get the cookies from **NAvigating** function,when i execute the code,

```
cookies = browserControl.GetCookies();
```

I get an exception stating that,

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
```

What is the problem? how should i get the cookies in **NAvigating** function??

Answer (score 0):

> The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the
>   object's current state.

I guess this is by design. It won't give you the existing cookies because they are already stale and it won't give you the new cookies because they are not created yet.

Comment: do you mean, i can't get it in __NAvigating__ function, by any other means??

Comment: You can get it before navigation and after navigation but not while. The first two option should be enough.

Comment: then how to get it before navigating??

Comment: Every time there is a navigated event save the cookies to a local variable. Next time there is a navigating event you can just read it from your own variable. Obviously cookies will be null before the first navigated event.